# Checking for True returned form codeigniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want a simple but correct way to check if true or false was returned from a codeigniter model.

SO

If true was returned by my model, can I just do this in the controller?

```
if($variable = $this->ci_model->model_method($user_id)){
 // true, was returned do something
}
```

Or do i have to specifically test if true was returned, and how can i do that?

Comment: No need to do special if TRUE return . You can also use `if($this->ci_model->model_method($user_id))`

Comment: So if i wanted to check for false can i do this  `if(!$this->ci_model->model_method($user_id))`

Comment: Yes correct !!! Go ahead

Answer (score 2):

**Do this  :**

```
 $variable = $this->ci_model->model_method($user_id);
 if(!empty($variable))
 {
   return true
 }
  else 
 {
  return false;
 }
```

**OR you can this way :**

```
if($this->ci_model->model_method($user_id))
 {
   return true
 }
  else 
 {
  return false;
 }
```